# SQL Count between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count

I currently have two separate queries in SQL Server that count the number of times a table contains a unique ID in a week. I would like to display these using one query, not two.

This data is held in two separate views, hence my writing two queries. These are `ActivityPointer` and `Asp_dealercallreport`.

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
    OwnerIDName, 
    COUNT(Distinct ActivityID) AS CalendarEvents
FROM 
    ActivityPointer
WHERE
    /*Specify Activity code for Calendar Events*/
    ActivityTypeCode = '4201'
    /*Specify Calendar Events from this week only*/
    AND ScheduledStart >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) / 7 * 7, 0)
    AND ScheduledStart <= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 0)
    /*Specify users to be reported on by Name*/
    AND OwnerIdName IN ('John Doe', 'Jane Doe')
GROUP BY 
    OwnerIDName
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT 
    OwnerIDName, 
    COUNT(Distinct Asp_dealercallreportId) AS DealerVisits
FROM 
    Asp_dealercallreport
    /*Specify Calendar Events from this week only*/
WHERE    
    asp_callreportdate >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) / 7 * 7, 0)
    AND asp_callreportdate <= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 0)
    /*Specify  to be reported on by Name*/
    AND OwnerIdName IN ('John Doe', 'Jane Doe')
GROUP BY 
    OwnerIDName
```

Thanks

Comment: Usually, you can use some of the system tables, which contains only one row or create a temporary one, and then solve both queries as a subquery, so you will have one row, and two fields on the same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can simply use INNER JOIN operator? Like this:

```
SELECT 
    ap.OwnerIDName, 
    COUNT(Distinct ap.ActivityID) AS CalendarEvents, 
    COUNT(Distinct a_dcr.Asp_dealercallreportId) AS DealerVisits
FROM 
    ActivityPointer ap
INNER JOIN 
    Asp_dealercallreport a_dcr ON ap.OwnerIDName=a_dcr.OwnerIDName
WHERE
/*Specify Activity code for Calendar Events*/
    ap.ActivityTypeCode = '4201'
/*Specify Calendar Events from this week only*/
    AND ap.ScheduledStart >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) / 7 * 7, 0)
    AND ap.ScheduledStart <= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 0)
/*Specify Calendar Events from this week only*/
    AND a_dcr.asp_callreportdate >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) / 7 * 7, 0)
    AND a_dcr.asp_callreportdate <= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 0)
/*Specify users to be reported on by Name*/
    AND ap.OwnerIdName IN ('John Doe', 'Jane Doe')
GROUP BY 
    ap.OwnerIDName
```

Comment: Wizardry. Thank you. I need to brush up on my JOINs. When I was doing this I was coming up with some strange results.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT OwnerIDName,
       COUNT(Distinct case when ScheduledStart >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) / 7 * 7, 0) AND
                                ScheduledStart <= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 0)
                           then ActivityID end) AS CalendarEvents_Scheduled,
       COUNT(Distinct case when asp_callreportdate >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) / 7 * 7, 0) and
                                asp_callreportdate <= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 0)
                           then ActivityID end) AS CalendarEvents_asp
FROM ActivityPointer
WHERE ActivityTypeCode = '4201' AND
      OwnerIdName IN ('John Doe', 'Jane Doe')
GROUP BY OwnerIDName;
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the point that there are actually two tables used in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Using a standard SQL UNION will provide you with the output of both queries in one result set. As long as they have same number and type of columns:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

```
SELECT OwnerIDName, COUNT(Distinct ActivityID) AS CalendarEvents
FROM ActivityPointer
WHERE
/*Specify Activity code for Calendar Events*/
    ActivityTypeCode = '4201'
/*Specify Calendar Events from this week only*/
AND ScheduledStart >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) / 7 * 7, 0)
AND ScheduledStart <= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 0)
/*Specify users to be reported on by Name*/
AND OwnerIdName IN ('John Doe', 'Jane Doe')
GROUP BY OwnerIDName    
UNION
SELECT OwnerIDName, COUNT(Distinct Asp_dealercallreportId) AS DealerVisits
FROM Asp_dealercallreport
/*Specify Calendar Events from this week only*/
WHERE    asp_callreportdate >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) / 7  * 7, 0)
AND    asp_callreportdate <= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 0)
/*Specify  to be reported on by Name*/
AND    OwnerIdName IN ('John Doe', 'Jane Doe')
GROUP BY OwnerIDName
```